# The shift of the x-axis marks achartengine barchart compared to the values

Tags: achartengine

I am new to writing apps. I created a BarChart using aChartEngine for my Android app. I cannot set the labels in the center for the x-axis in my chart.

```
private void initChart() {
        mCurrentSeries = new XYSeries("");
        mDataset.addSeries(mCurrentSeries);
        XYSeriesRenderer mCurrentRenderer = new 
XYSeriesRenderer();
        mCurrentRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(20);
        mCurrentRenderer.setColor(Color.BLACK);

mCurrentRenderer.setChartValuesTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        mCurrentRenderer.setFillPoints(false);
        mCurrentRenderer.setLineWidth(5);
        mCurrentRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

        mCurrentSeries2 = new XYSeries("");
        mDataset.addSeries(mCurrentSeries2);
        XYSeriesRenderer mCurrentRendererRed = new 
XYSeriesRenderer();
        mCurrentRendererRed.setChartValuesTextSize(20);
        mCurrentRendererRed.setColor(Color.RED);


mCurrentRendererRed.setChartValuesTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
       // mCurrentRendererRed.setFillPoints(false);
        mCurrentRendererRed.setLineWidth(5);
        mCurrentRendererRed.setDisplayChartValues(true);

        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(mCurrentRenderer);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(mCurrentRendererRed);
        mRenderer.setBarSpacing(1);
        mRenderer.setXLabels(9);
        mRenderer.setYLabels(30);
        mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
        mRenderer.setXAxisMax(17);
        mRenderer.setYAxisMin(2);
        mRenderer.setYAxisMax(4);
        mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(30);
        mRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0,Color.RED);
        mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.RED);
        mRenderer.setYAxisAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT, 0);
        mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT, 0);
        mRenderer.setShowGridY(true);
        mRenderer.setShowGridX(true);
        mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
        mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] {0, 50, 0, 50});
        mRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.15);
        mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true);
        mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
        mRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
    }
```

that's what happened [https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWRuT.png]